# Calculate a factorial with large numbers

Tags: probability

So I'm given an interesting assignment in probability that states the following:

A rabbit stands on the point ***0*** of the ***X-axis*** and starts jumping on it from one point to another. Every time it makes either one jump left or one jump right with a probability of jumping left that is being equaled to $\frac{1}{3}$. Let ***X*** be a random variable that takes the value of ***1*** if it jumps right and ***-1*** if it jumps left. Using ***X*** find the probability that after 100 jumps the rabbit will be at a distance of ***10 units from the starting point***.

So I don't know how to use X but I found that if ***Z*** is the random variable that is the distance from the starting point after 100 jumps. So the probability of the rabbit landing on a point that is at least at a 10 unit distance from the starting point is

### 1 - ( P{ Z = 0} + P{ Z = 2 } + P{ Z = 4 } + P{ Z = 6 } + P{ Z = 8 }

### (Because the rabbit takes 100 jumps it cannot land on an odd unit)

Since the rabbit can take any route it want but it has to land on a specific unit for example 2 then

### P{ Z = 2 } = ${100}\choose{51}$ $(\frac{2}{3})^{51}(\frac{1}{3})^{49}$

### The rabbit has to go 51 units and 49 units left in any order it likes

So I'm stuck here because the combinations formula is $\frac{100!}{51!*49!}$ and I can't calculate nor use the factorial formula to cancel some values out.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are just asking for a numerical approximation to that expression?  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BinomialCoefficient%5B100,51%5D*(2%2F3)%5E51*(1%2F3)%5E49) has no problem with it. Or were you after something else?

Comment: Yes but this is an exam question and we can't use Wolfram there. I think that my method of approach for the solution is incorrect. Or is it not?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve.  The first time you state it, you say "find the probability that after 100 jumps the rabbit will be at a distance of 10 units from the starting point."  In which case formulas like the one you wrote down should be good.  The second time you speak of "a point that is at least at a 10 unit distance from the starting point ". Which did you mean?

Comment: I will point out that in an academic setting where you are first learning the tools and common equations that arise in these types of problems, not only is it perfectly acceptable to leave things unsimplified, *it is often encouraged!*  Seeing things in the unsimplified form lets the reader get a glimpse as to how your thought process worked getting you to that point.

Comment: Either way, your approach only addresses one half of the board..the rabbit could end up $10$ from the start on either side, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$\dfrac{100!}{51!*49!}
=\dfrac{100!\cdot 50}{51\cdot 50!*50!}
=\dfrac{50}{51}\binom{100}{50}
$
and use the approximation
$\binom{2n}{n}
\approx \dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$.

The Wikipedia article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient
has the approximation
$\binom{2n}{n}
= \dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1-\dfrac{c_n}{n}\right)
$
where
$\dfrac19 < c_n < \dfrac18$.